# How to encapsulate bootstrapvue table twice

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I hope that after encapsulating the Table, the type can be judged by the field.
For example: element UI, you can judge the type by traversing the head, and perform secondary encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<template #cell()="data">
  <template v-if="data.field.type === 'link'">
    link: {{ data.value }}
  </template>
</template>
```

solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.